# 'Cannot resolve symbol' when using an if/else statement

Tags: java, string, class, gwt, compiler-errors

I'm just wondering why I get a "cannot resolve symbol initialText" with the following code. isItA is a boolean which the user selects earlier depending on which type of text (A or B) they are about to paste into the text area. There are 2 potential strings for initialText, and the one which is outputted depends on the boolean isItA. I dont get why this error pops when i use initialText outside the if/else statement; if is inside the 'if/else' statement, the compiler should be able to resolve the string outside right?  I'm currently using GWT in IntelliJ. At this point I am still sort of noob at java, so a basic explanation of why this is happening would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks in advance. A snippet of the code is below.

```
protected TextArea getNewTextArea() {
    if ( newTextArea == null ) {

        if (isItA){
            final String initialText = "Please paste valid text A here, and then
            press" + "the \"" + Labels.ADD_A_BUTTON_TEXT + "\" button.";

        }else{
            final String initialText = "Please paste valid text B here, and then press " + "the \"" + Labels.ADD_B_BUTTON_TEXT + "\" button.";
        }


        newTextArea = new TextArea();
        newTextArea.setText( initialText );
        newTextArea.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick( ClickEvent clickEvent ) {
                // If the text is still the original text, then clear it.
                if ( newTextArea.getText().equals( initialText ) ) {
                    newTextArea.setText( "" );
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if it is so, then you wouldnt be able to override initialText in your second declaration as it is final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

initialText is unresovlable because it is not within the given code block scope.

To fix this, declare intitalText before the if/else statement like so:

```
protected TextArea getNewTextArea() {
    if ( newTextArea == null ) {

        final String initialText;
        if (isItA){
            initialText = "Please paste valid text A here, and then
            press" + "the \"" + Labels.ADD_A_BUTTON_TEXT + "\" button.";

        }else{
            initialText = "Please paste valid text B here, and then press " + "the \"" + Labels.ADD_B_BUTTON_TEXT + "\" button.";
        }


        newTextArea = new TextArea();
        newTextArea.setText( initialText );
        newTextArea.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick( ClickEvent clickEvent ) {
                // If the text is still the original text, then clear it.
                if ( newTextArea.getText().equals( initialText ) ) {
                    newTextArea.setText( "" );
                }

            }
        } );
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to do this so i can keep it as '**final** String initialText;'? Its just I would like to keep that string from being modified after that if/else code block.

Comment: initialText (the way it is defined) may be final.  I've update the answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `final String initialText` is local to `if-else` block.So, declare it outside if-else block and than initialize inside it.

Answer (score 0):

initialText only exists inside the curlies block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move initialText to right below the beginning of function block

protected TextArea getNewTextArea() {

```
            String initialText ...
```